# Dynamic Fields for Drupal Content Type

Tags: drupal, cck

I have a product, and I want it to have many changeable attributes so I did it with Taxonomy,
 now I have a list that holds "price, color, shape", 
 how do I let a user choose from it within the "add product" page and let him write a color for instance?

**UPDATE** 
I found something called [Taxonomy Field](http://drupal.org/project/cck_taxonomy). 
That is almost exactly what I'm looking for. 
It lets me have a list of taxonomy which I use as attributes 
and even lets the user create new ones. 
One thing is missing - I want a text field to be created for each attribute 
the user chooses.

for example: 
Attribute: Color        Value: White 
so the attribute Color is a Taxonomy field and the value is simply 
 an empty text field created for it (I can't just add a text field because 
the number of attributes is dynamic)

**SOLVED**

In the new [Beta version of CCK](http://drupal.org/node/484068) there's a group 
type that's called "MutliGroup" that does exactly what I wanted. 
Turns out this issue has been discussed a lot and it seems 
that they are adding it to the new CCK3 which would be stable 
on Drupal7

Comment: Just to clarify, you're have a sort of shopping cart, where you have a product that can be multiple colors, and you want to let the user choose which color they want when adding the product to their cart?

Comment: well, it's not a shopping cart, I have many products being compared, so some have color_field, price_per_month_field etc.
the thing is that some have these fields and some have fields like density or what-not and I want each of these attribute to be a field... but I don't want each product to have all those fields... seems like some sort of taxonomy but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

Drat, a whole answer then I reread the comments and lost my post.

That answer boiled down to [Autocomplete Widgets for CCK Text and Number](http://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_widgets), which is still a neat module to know about.

For the sort of hierarchical structure you describe with dynamic field availability, it sounds like you want some sort of javascripty hierarchical selection mechanism. Like, say [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select).